# Decoding code text to ASCII failure

Tags: javascript, html

My program codes normal text to ASCII. Everything works well, except the decoding doesn't work. What is wrong?

Also, I don't want that commas appear when the coded text is printed. Oh, and I want to include the Caesar cipher too.

```js
function code() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < leer.length; i++) {
    array[i] = leer[i].charCodeAt(0);
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array;
}

function decode() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
  for (var i = 0, char; char = leer[i]; i++) {
    array[i] = String.fromCharCode(leer[i].charCodeAt(0));
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Escriba el Mensaje:<br><br>
  <input type="text" id="1" name="mensaje" rows="10" cols="40">
  <br><br>
  <br><br> Elige una opción:
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cifra" value="Cifrar" onclick="code()">
  <input type="button" name="decifra" value="Decifrar" onclick="decode()">
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="2" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Your decoding and encoding functions both appear to work fine.

Comment: No, coding function works fine. Decoding doesn't. @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 0):

you should use string string instead array in decoding function

```
function decode() {
var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
str = "";
for (var i = 0, char; char = leer[i]; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(leer[i].charCodeAt(0));
}
document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + str;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrayname.join(' '); 
here is the working snippet.

```js
function code() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
   //debugger;
  for (var i = 0; i < leer.length; i++) {
    array[i] = leer[i].charCodeAt(0);
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array.join(' ');
}

function decode() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
 //debugger;
  for (var i = 0, char; char = leer[i]; i++) {
    array[i] = String.fromCharCode(leer[i].charCodeAt(0));
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exCSS.css">
</head>

<body>
<form>
  Escriba el Mensaje:<br><br>
  <textarea id="1" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <br><br> Elige una opción:
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cifra" value="Cifrar" onclick="code()">
  <input type="button" name="decifra" value="Decifrar" onclick="decode()">
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="2" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, This will helpfull to you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function code() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
   //debugger;
  for (var i = 0; i < leer.length; i++) {
    array[i] = leer[i].charCodeAt(0);
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array.join('');
}

function decode() {
  var leer = document.getElementById('1').value,
      array = [];
 //debugger;
  for (var i = 0, char; char = leer[i]; i++) {
    array[i] = String.fromCharCode(leer[i].charCodeAt(0));
  }
  document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = 'Chale, chale ' + array.join('');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exCSS.css">
</head>

<body>
<form>
  Escriba el Mensaje:<br><br>
  <input type="text" id="1" />      
  <br><br> Elige una opción:
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cifra" value="Cifrar" onclick="code()">
  <input type="button" name="decifra" value="Decifrar" onclick="decode()">
  <br><br>
  <textarea id="2" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```